# how to call function in div tag without using *ngIf In Angular 2

Tags: html, angular, typescript

In I want to filter JSON in nested loop I have filters in child loop, but ngFor but I also want that filter at parent level also angular 2 I am using nglf To call the function it working but I want another method because it calls contentiously

```
<div *ngFor="let partyAddress of addressDataShow?.data" >
    <div class="row bg-greybg"  *ngIf="companyFilter(partyAddress) || selectedaddress === 'ALL' || isAddressAvailabale > 0">
 <div *ngFor="let partyAddressDetails of partyAddress?.company_address">
          <div *ngIf="selectedaddress === 'ALL' || partyAddressDetails.address_type.indexOf(selectedaddress) > -1">
            <p>Filter data</p>
          </div>
        </div>
<div>
</div>
```

Comment: can you please post your code ???

Comment: here is my jsfiddle link https://jsfiddle.net/h3j1fkLh/

Comment: in second line i calling function using *ngIf what can i use instead of ngIf  to call function if makes call multiple times

Comment: *ngIf is for not showing that particular html part in dom and view either you can use  
<div [hidden]="companyFilter(partyAddress)" ></div>

Comment: please note that *ngIf and [hidden] can not be use in the same div in angular it will throw fatal error

Comment: [hidde] also same working *ngIF

Comment: Can we use directive or anything other to call a function to check each part of for loop?

Comment: I have adden a method if call than function only then you can call with {{functionName()}}  inside div tag

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to call that function only. Then just call the function using  double curly brace `{{functionName()}}`

```
<div *ngFor="let partyAddress of addressDataShow?.data" >
    <div class="row bg-greybg"  > {{companyFilter(partyAddress)}}
        <div *ngFor="let partyAddressDetails of partyAddress?.company_address">
          <div *ngIf="selectedaddress === 'ALL' || partyAddressDetails.address_type.indexOf(selectedaddress) > -1">
            <p>Filter data</p>
          </div>
        </div>
    <div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

`*ngIf` is not the worst choice in this case. What's your reason for avoiding `*ngIf`?

Basically there's two other options coming into my mind:

1. Switch case
   Example:

   ```
   <div [ngSwitch]="yourExpression">      
       <div *ngSwitchCase="match_expression_1">Show it when condition 1 applies</div>
       <div *ngSwitchCase="match_expression_2">Show it when condition 2 applies</div></div>
   ```
2. [hidden] directive

_

```
<div [hidden]="yourExpressionHere"></div>
```

Please let me know if that solves your problem.

Answer (score 0):

or you can define your custom directive:

```
// ./app/shared/hidden.directive.ts
import { Directive, ElementRef, Input, Renderer } from '@angular/core';

@Directive({ selector: '[myHidden]' })
export class HiddenDirective {

    constructor(public el: ElementRef, public renderer: Renderer) {}

    @Input() myHidden: boolean;

    ngOnInit(){
        // Use renderer to render the emelemt with styles
        console.log(this.myHidden)
        if(this.myHidden) {
            console.log('hide');
            this.renderer.setElementStyle(this.el.nativeElement, 'display', 'none');
        }
    }
}
```